# Evolution hangs for 10-30 seconds after replying/writing new email

Tags: linux-mint, evolution

I'm running linux mint 17.3 and I recently switched to using Evolution(v3.10.4) with the EWS plugin to handle my work emails.

Most everything was working fine, and it was a much easier setup than thunderbird at least as far as setting it up using exchange, but I am having one odd issue. I noticed that whenever I try to write a new email or reply to an email the entire program hangs for roughly 10 to 30 seconds which is making working with it much more difficult than it should be.

Comment: What is the process(es?) doing? `strace` or such may help debug.

Comment: I'm only using evolution for the calendar, but I also get this hang whenever I edit an event.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running seahorse, this may be your problem. Looked up this trouble and it is the delay in seahorse encrypting your id & password to the mail server. The fix was to go to seahorse and blank your keyring password which forces your password to go out as text.